# how to compare the data of two tables and fetch the unmatched records in plsql

Tags: plsql

table 1

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 5 | 6 |

table 2

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 5 | 7 |

how to fetch the table 2 second row record which is mismatch in plsql,
how to write query in plsql if both tables have millions of records  .Please help

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/26595185/13927534

Comment: but if table has millions of records ,it will take more time .how to write plsql which takes less time

Answer (score 0):

You can do that directly with SQL like below :

Here I am using the ***decode*** function to properly handle the comparison between possible null values.
But, if you know that none of the columns involved in your comparison accept NULL values, you can just use t1.colX = t2.colX.

```sql
SELECT t2.*
FROM table_2 t2 
LEFT JOIN table_1 t1
ON  DECODE(t1.col1, t2.col1, 1) = 1
AND DECODE(t1.col2, t2.col2, 1) = 1
AND DECODE(t1.col3, t2.col3, 1) = 1
WHERE t1.col1 IS NULL 
;
```

If PL/SQL is really needed for your case, you can just put the above query in a PL/SQL block like this:

```sql
BEGIN
dbms_output.enable(buffer_size => 2000);
dbms_output.put_line('col1, col2, col3');  
for rws in (
            SELECT t2.col1, t2.col2, t2.col3
            FROM table_2 t2 
            LEFT JOIN table_1 t1
            ON  DECODE(t1.col1, t2.col1, 1) = 1
            AND DECODE(t1.col2, t2.col2, 1) = 1
            AND DECODE(t1.col3, t2.col3, 1) = 1
            WHERE t1.col1 IS NULL
           )
           LOOP
            dbms_output.put_line(rws.col1||', '||rws.col2||', '||rws.col3);
           END LOOP;
END;
/
```

You could also try this sql query to improve performance :

```sql
SELECT col1, col2, col3, MIN(source_tab) source_tab
FROM (
  SELECT col1, col2, col3, 'table_1' FROM table_1 UNION ALL
  SELECT col1, col2, col3, 'table_2' FROM table_2
)
GROUP BY col1, col2, col3
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT source_tab) = 1
   AND MIN(source_tab) = 'table_2'
;
```

Comment: Will this query be faster if I have millions of records

Comment: You should test it in your environment to make sure it is faster.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be PL/SQL? If so, what kind of result do you expect? Store rows into another table? Collection? Display them? Explain, please.

---

If you just want to get rows from `table2` that don't exist in `table1`, how about simple & fast `minus` set operator, executed at SQL level?

Sample data:

```
SQL> with
  2  table1 (col1, col2, col3) as
  3    (select 1, 2, 3 from dual union all
  4     select 4, 5, 6 from dual union all
  5     select 7, 8, 9 from dual
  6    ),
  7  table2 (col1, col2, col3) as
  8    (select 1, 2, 3 from dual union all
  9     select 4, 5, 7 from dual union all
 10     select 9, 8, 7 from dual
 11    )
```

Query:

```
 12  select * from table2
 13  minus
 14  select * from table1;

      COL1       COL2       COL3
---------- ---------- ----------
         4          5          7
         9          8          7

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to merge into structure as below:

```
Merge Into table1 t1 
    Using (Select col1,
                  col2,
                  col3
             From table2) t2
     ON (t2.col1 = t1.col1
         And t2.col2 = t2.col2
         And t2.col3 = t2.col3)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN -- Means that all columns matched column by column
      -- Do it what you want, you can use column values also.
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN -- Means that there is a not matched column(s) 
      -- Do it what you want, you can use column values also.
    ;
```

It works properly with huge data and because of less detail about the question I wrote it as a general answer.